# Websphere MQ reconnectOnException

Tags: ibm-mq, spring-jmx

I have configured DMLC and SingleConnectionFactory for my WMQ listener.
Everything is working as expected except the failover scenario.

It enters onException method as soon as the connection is lost. That's okay.

But the queue is not yet up so the DMLC tries to reconnect but after failure on reconnect it is again entering in the onException method. It should not enter in the onException method again.

Any help on this?

Comment: onException will be called each time exception occurs (see doReceiveAndExecute). What does "queue is not yet up mean"?

Comment: The reconnect options vary greatly depending on the QMgr version and the client version.  which version of each are you using?